# how to identify parts of a file bash

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu

i have a file like this :

```
fail  
test1
test2
test3

pass
test1
test2
test3

notrun
test1
test2
test3
```

Notice that in this file there will always be a space.

This file is generated automatically by an external script in bash, so i would like to split this file in 3 files in order to analyze this information easier, but i dont know how. I was thinking in grab all pass tests in a file, all fail tests in other file and not run tests in the third file, i have a good knowledge of bash but i dont have any idea of how do this, or even you can show me a better way to do it.
and necessarily it needs to be in bash script :)

Please i would appreciate your help in this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is simpler using `awk` with null `RS` (record separator):

```
awk -v RS= 'NF{print > "file" NR}' file
```

Then verify results:

```
cat file1
fail
test1
test2
test3

cat file2
pass
test1
test2
test3

cat file3
notrun
test1
test2
test3
```

Comment: Wooowwww this is exactly what im looking for,, thanks a lot @anubhava

Comment: one more thing, how can i do for specific where i wish the file located ?

Comment: You can use: `print > "/tmp/file" NR` to have those files inside `/tmp/` folder